# Why is Intellij importing the "wrong" SecureRandom class (Java)?

Tags: java, secure-random

I'm writing a programm that requires a SecureRandom objekt. After creating it, Intellij automatically imported **"sun.security.provider.SecureRandom"**.
But with this import, I'm unable to call many methods. For example I'm unable to *"nextInt()"* or *"doubles()"* and many other methods.

But if i manually import **"java.security.SecureRandom"**, I'm able to generate random numbers with these methods above.

But the **"sun.security.provider.SecureRandom"** import does provide other methods like *"engineGenerateSeed"*, that I can't call with **"java.security.SecureRandom"**.

So my actual questin is, why are there two different possible import (I can't import both at the same time) and what are they for?

Comment: They are different implementations. They just happen to be called the same thing. Why does my friend Tom look different to your brother Tom?

Comment: "I can't import both at the same time" Right, because then which one would `SecureRandom` refer to in your code? If you need both -- and you don't -- then you can import one and refer to the fully qualified name for the other (e.g. in your class you would use `SecureRandom` and `java.security.SecureRandom`)

Comment: You can use both in your code.  You just have to refer to each one using their fully resolved class name.  You can no longer use the short class name in your code.  You have to spell them out.  You should avoid packages that start with "sun".  They are clearly marked as possibly being deprecated and removed at any time.